# plsql what is wrong with this code error 'INTO list is of wrong type'

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can someone please help me? Why do I get this error "INTO list is of wrong type"?

```
DECLARE 
 TYPE v_dept_table IS TABLE OF DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

v_record_dept_table v_dept_table;

v_loop_count NUMBER := 10;
v_dept_no NUMBER := 1;



BEGIN
FOR v_dept_no IN 1..v_loop_count LOOP 
    SELECT DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME
    INTO v_record_dept_table
    FROM DEPARTMENTS 
    WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = v_dept_no;

    v_dept_no := v_dept_no + 1;

    INSERT
    INTO v_dept_table 
    VALUES  v_record_dept_table;
END LOOP;    

FOR indx IN NVL (v_dept_table.FIRST, 0) .. NVL (v_dept_table.LAST, -1) 
LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_dept_table(indx));
END LOOP; 
END;
```

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 16, column 14:
> PLS-00597: expression 'V_RECORD_DEPT_TABLE' in the INTO list is of wrong type
> ```

Why is it a wrong type? I'm using the hr schema from Oracle

Comment: see: [A) PL/SQL  SELECT INTO – selecting one column example](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-select-into/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly like that; you've done several things wrong. I tried to fix your code (with as little modifications as possible); have a look, read comments I wrote, compare it to your code. Side note: I used Scott's `DEPT` table as I don't have your `DEPARTMENTS`.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE v_dept_table IS TABLE OF dept.dname%TYPE
  3        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  4
  5     v_record_dept_table  v_dept_table;
  6
  7     v_loop_count         NUMBER := 10;
  8     v_dept_no            NUMBER := 1;
  9  BEGIN
 10     FOR v_dept_no IN 1 .. v_loop_count
 11     LOOP
 12        BEGIN
 13           SELECT dname
 14             INTO v_record_dept_table (v_dept_no) --> you're missing "(v_dept_no)"
 15             FROM dept
 16            WHERE deptno = v_dept_no;
 17        -- Don't manually increment FOR loop variable; Oracle does it itself
 18        -- v_dept_no := v_dept_no + 1;
 19
 20        -- You can't insert into "type"; besides, you've already inserted into V_RECORD_DEPT_TABLE.
 21        -- INSERT INTO v_dept_table VALUES v_record_dept_table;
 22        EXCEPTION
 23           WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 24           THEN
 25              NULL;
 26        END;
 27     END LOOP;
 28
 29     -- loop through V_RECORD_DEPT_TABLE (collection), not V_DEPT_TABLE (type). No need for NVL.
 30     FOR indx IN NVL (v_record_dept_table.FIRST, 0) ..
 31                 NVL (v_record_dept_table.LAST, -1)
 32     LOOP
 33        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_record_dept_table (indx));
 34     END LOOP;
 35  END;
 36  /
ACCOUNTING

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, see whether this helps. I used built-in type (`sys.odcivarchar2list`) and `BULK COLLECT INTO` (performs better).

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_record_dept_table  SYS.odcivarchar2list;
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT dname
  5       BULK COLLECT INTO v_record_dept_table
  6       FROM dept;
  7
  8     FOR indx IN v_record_dept_table.FIRST .. v_record_dept_table.LAST
  9     LOOP
 10        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_record_dept_table (indx));
 11     END LOOP;
 12  END;
 13  /
ACCOUNTING
RESEARCH
SALES
OPERATIONS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```